# I want to execute a query in python by template.format method where the argument in format comes by transversing a string.I'm getting an error

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

```py
for i in range(0,len(l)):
 c = l[(i)]
 st = 'select Item_name,Price from stationary where code = {}'.format(c)
 cur1.execute(st)
data = cur1.fetchall()
for j in data:
 print(j)
st1 = 'select sum(Price) from stationary'
print("Total cost = ",cur1.execute(st1))
```

st is the query to be executed in mysql with cursor "cur1". I'm trying to get the values in format by transversing a list but i'm getting an error.

Comment: 'l' is a list that will store values given by the user

Answer (score 0):

You are not quoting the values in `l`, which is your immediate problem, but in fact you should not be doing that yourself.  Let the adapter do it.

Next, remember that `execute` does not return results.  You have to use the cursor fetch functions to do that.

Also, `execute` calls are not cumulative.  When you do an `execute` that returns results, you must fetch the results before you do another query.

```
for c in l:
  st = 'select Item_name,Price from stationary where code = %s'
  cur1.execute(st,(c,))
  for row in cur1.fetchall():
      print(row)
st1 = 'select sum(Price) from stationary;'
cur1.execute(st1)
print("Total cost = ",cur1.fetchone())
```